# How come the friction is directed upwards (the one that will arise from the vertical wall)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

[image]

Well as you can see in the image, the problem involved drawing the free body diagram of the system when a force $F$ is applied to the disk which is stuck between a rough vertical wall and a frictionless diagonal ladder. I mean if we think of it even though demonstrations, doesn't the direction of the friction in the free body diagram become upwards resisting the motion in a clockwise direction? To my eyes, the direction in which it is said to be rotating and the direction of the friction resisting it did not make any sense. what do you think?

Comment: Interesting problem. I could be wrong, but it seems to me the static friction force of the wall acts downwards (to prevent the disc from sliding up the wall) and the rotation of the disc should be counter clockwise, not clockwise, assuming the maximum possible static friction force is not exceeded.

Comment: @BobD Yes, to my eyes as well.

Answer (score 0):

> How come the friction is directed upwards (the one that will arise
> from the vertical wall)?

It isn't. The static friction force is directed downwards. As long as the maximum possible static friction force is not exceeded, it will cause counter clockwise rotation of the disc without slipping on the vertical wall.

Consider what would happen if there were no friction on the vertical wall. In that case the disc will slide up both the smooth wedge and the vertical wall without rotating. Since friction opposes relative motion of the surfaces, it would oppose the disc sliding up the wall, i.e., it would act downward.

For what it's worth, I took a ping pong ball and placed it between a rough vertical surface and a smooth surface wedge, as in your diagram. Upon pushing on the ball with the wedge it moved up the wedge and wall while rotating counter clockwise. Since the disc can only rotate if there is a tangential friction force acting on it, its counter clockwise rotation had to be due to a downward static friction force. Try it yourself.

Hope this helps.